# Decoding MIME email from Gmail API - \r\n and 3D - Python

Tags: python, email, gmail-api, mime

I am currently using the Gmail API to read in some HTML emails in Python. I've decoded their body using:

```
base64.urlsafe_b64decode
```

After printing out the resulting HTML email, "\r\n" and "3D" are scattered around the HTML. I can't remove the "\r\n" because the \ and r and \ and n register as different characters (?) and I'm not sure where the "3D" comes from.

Is there something wrong with how I'm decoding it?

Here is the code:

```
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', q = 'is: unread').execute()

for index in range(len(results['messages'])):
    message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=results['messages'][index]['id'], format='raw').execute()

    msg_str = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(message['raw'].encode('UTF-8'))

    mime_msg = email.message_from_string(str(msg_str))

    print(mime_msg)

    service.users().messages().modify(userId='me', id=results['messages'][index]['id'], body = {'removeLabelIds': ['UNREAD']}).execute() # mark message as read
```

Comment: Here's a short sample: "</div></blockquote></div><br =\r\nclass=3D""></body></html>=\r\n\r\n--"

Comment: Yes, Users.messages: get.

Comment: I'm using the get request I found [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) 
to read an email of a specific id.

Comment: Yes, I am using email.message_from_string.

Comment: I just use the string email.message_from_string returns. Do I need to convert it somehow?

Comment: [`email.message_from_string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.parser.html#email.message_from_string) returns a message object, not a string. You need to use its methods to get the HTML payload. In Python 3.6+ you can apparently just use [`get_body`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage.get_body). In previous versions of Python, it’s more complicated.

Comment: Even though I am running python 3.6.1, it looks like I'll have to use the other method (since my emails are Message objects instead of EmailMessage objects).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution - I stopped using the email library from Python, and cast `msg_str` to a string (it is of type bytes). From there, I simply deleted `'\r\n'` from the string and replaced `'=3D'` with `'='`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a great solution, rather use something like

```
for email_part in message.walk(): 
    part_data = email_part.get_payload(decode=True)
```

Where message is a Python email.message.Message obj. Then perhaps uses something like BeautifulSoup to effectively analyse the HTML.
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

maksel's solution worked for me provided str.decode('utf-8') was set. The original code encoded instead of decoded the byte-string.

Hence, under python 3.7 we can replace as follows:

```
msg = msg.replace('\r\n', '').replace('=3D', '=')
```

Be wary as this solution did not work for all html tags in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I might be bit late. Some of the mentioned solutions worked. But to help others who are visiting here I thought to post this answer as it looks bit cleaner.

When building the mail object use `policy=email.policy.default`. This removes the mentioned `=3D`, `\r\n` etc.

```
mailobject = email.message_from_string(msg_str,  policy=email.policy.default)
```

If on Python 3.6+ you can use `get_body` and `get_content` methods.

```
if mailobject.is_multipart():
    body = mailobject.get_body(('html',))
else:
    body = mailobject.get_body(('plain',))

if body:
    body = body.get_content()

print(body)
```

> Above codes are very minimal just to suffice the answer. Here we assumed its either just plain or html. Remember to
> cater for other situations when handling
> emails.

**An Additional Unrelated Tip:**

As it is an encoding problem this answer also works with other similar situations. Like when trying to parse AWS SES emails pushed to s3 forwarding using an AWS Lambda Function(Python). I had to mention it here as this same issue occurred to me while trying to play with those.

In such case use it like this

```
s3_file = object_s3['Body'].read()
mailobject = email.message_from_string(s3_file.decode('utf-8'),  policy=email.policy.default)
```